# clearInterval() not working on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a HTML page with two buttons and I want to use setInterval to evaluate the function multiple times when I click the start button. This works just fine but I can't clear the interval. What am I doing wrong?

```
function intFunc (func, time) {
     interval = setInterval(func, time);
}

$("#startButton").on("click", intFunc(function () {
        $.post('link/to/php.php', function(data) {
                 //do something with data
        });
}, 1000));

$("#stopButton").on("click", function () {
         clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: where is the code for clearInterval() function or is it a built in function ?

Comment: it's a built in function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: could be a scope problem. try `console.log(interval)` in your click function to check if interval is being passed or not.

Comment: Also, your `on("click,` should be `on("click",`

Comment: oups, just a typo, I had to manually write the code

Comment: I agree with @KamranAdil this should work unless you haven't correctly defined your interval variable.

Comment: You need to declare your interval variable in the same scope as the click handler `var interval;` above your `intFunc` should do it!

Comment: You do realize that your intFunc function is being invoked immediately right?

Comment: @EJTH - no, you don't. Variables not scoped with `var` are automatically global. "Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed. "

Comment: Even if you leave your code as-is, the clearInterval works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cdaau730/

Comment: @j08691 NO, if the variable is not declared in a higher scope than the function it receeds in, it only exists in the scope of the function!

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. @EJTH I think you're right, it might just be a scope problem

Comment: Take a look at the answer though... because you can't do what you are trying either...

Comment: @EJTH - Really? See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cdaau730/10/. Add/remove a `var` in front of the variable and see what happens.

Comment: @KamranAdil yep, can see the inteval counting in my console

Comment: Well, turns out the thing is actually working. Browser problem

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies! You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

First, as the comments suggest you should declare `interval` above to make sure the scope is clear.

Second, you have a syntax problem. You're invoking `intFunc` straight away, and passing the result to `$("#startButton").on()`. This isn't what you want. What you should be passing as that second argument is a callback function. You could reorganize your code like this perhaps:

Third, declaring within a self invoking anonymous function will prevent pollution of the global scope.

```
(function() {
    var interval;

    $("#startButton").on("click", function(){
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $.post('link/to/php.php', function(data) {
               //do something with data
            });
        }, 1000);
    });

    $("#stopButton").on("click", function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
})();
```

Comment: I think you should make a clear example on how to stop a interval instead of this.

Comment: @AndrewLavers , noob question but by saying `var interval;` u mean but `var interval;` in the global scope  ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Who says it is global? You really should do as little as possible in global scope. Use closures, it is essentially just wrapping you code in a function like so `(function(){ /* ... code lives here in its own scope ... */ })()`.! That way you can isolate your code, there is alot you can do with it, but that cannot fit into a comment :-)

Comment: @EJTH , Thanks alooot :) i am learning IIFE's and i must say they are powerful .

Comment: @EJTH is correct, global scope should be avoided whenever possible. I'll edit the answer to incorporate this and stopping the interval.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should (or could) have written it:

```
var interval;
$("#startButton").on("click", function(){
      interval = setInterval(function () {
         $.post('link/to/php.php', function(data) {
               //do something with data
         });
      }, 1000);
});

$("#stopButton").on("click", function () {
         clearInterval(interval);
});
```

You cannot use functions like that, because when you write:

```
$("#startButton").on("click", intFunc(..));
```

You are executing intFunc immediately, and that doesnt return anything.